# Pronunciation of מסכתא (tractate)

Tags: pronunciation, ashkenazi, aramaic

Sometimes I hear מסֶכתא (pronounce: masechta) pronounced as מסִכתא (pronounce: masichta) by some people, particularly in Ashkenazi circles. Why is this?

Comment: Maybe someone with an Artscroll (or other vowelized) gemara can look up one of [these](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=003922636974222575695%3A8f0kdrh08aq&ie=Windows-1255&q=%EE%F1%EB%FA%E0&sa=+Search+#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%90&gsc.page=1).

Comment: @Adam, thanks for the clarification. Incidentally, I've still never heard that pronunciation.

Comment: [This series of books](http://www.pearlmancta.com/TorahLishmaInstitute.htm) vocalizes it the second way.

Comment: AdamMosheh My apologies if I offended you. @SethJ Reading words like that (with all kubutz's) was a shtik we used to do back in elementary school when reading rashi without vowels. Although it sounds silly, doing so gave me my first conception of _matres lectionis_ because the word would gain syllables.

Comment: @WAF - Submit that as an answer if you want.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Unless you are implying that it is _because_ of that book series that Ashkenazi people pronounce it that way, I don't think that's much of an answer.

Comment: There are different pronunciations for different groups, like you said. Ashkenazim, different Mizrachi (Eastern Jews), Yemenites and others all have different pronunciations of words and sounds. Here's an article with a bit more information on the topic: http://www.hebrewtoday.com/content/hebrew-pronunciation

Comment: @HebrewEnthusiast Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for that tidbit. I've made it into a comment as it doesn't precisely deal with the word in question, but it is interesting none the less. You should definitely check out the Hebrew Language Proposal over on Area 51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage